# Trying to purposely corrupt data in a photo to get the effect

Tags: photo, photos, corruption, data-recovery, corrupt-data

I'm trying to purposely corrupt the data in a photo and recover it to get the cool effect it leaves behind.  I don't want to recreate it in Photoshop, i'd like to do it organically if that make sense. I'm looking for any information on corruption and recovery. what makes this crazy effect happen.

I've attached a image of what im looking for..again if anyone has articles or any information on this subject i'd like to be indulged! Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think we kind of need more context here.  What software are you using?  Do you want a specific effect?  Usually this sort of stuff is just caused when the underlying binary gets mucked with.  You can probably reproduce it just by messing with the stream while you are reading it.

Comment: I'm taking a photo from my nikon d5200 and putting it on my computer(windows).  beyond that i any program I could use I just want to know how to do it. I figured thatI could through it onto a usb and remove the use before its copied on. But what type of usb? do modern usbs protect against this. There is just too much I dont know.

Comment: Well, if you want to take a super simple approach, open up your image in your favorite text editor (Right Click > Open With > Notepad) and then just type in random characters throughout the file.  You'll quickly see things deteriorate next time you open it.  Not sure how to reproduce the effect above, but you'd have to isolate what exactly is happening (looks like some weird operations are happening on write) and reproduce those same operations.  It's a matter of comparing the source with the effect and guessing the algorithms that caused the errors.